# Connecting nodes with each other with the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I am trying a couple of things with my audio:

- Increase / decrease the overall volume of the audio.
- Increase / decrease the volume and delay of a specific channel (left).

I have this code:

```
var audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext,
    context = new audioContext(),
    sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById('audio'));

// Nodes to control the left channel
var channelSplitterNode = context.createChannelSplitter(1);

var leftChannelGainNode = context.createGain();
leftChannelGainNode.gain.value = 1.10;
channelSplitterNode.connect(leftChannelGainNode, 0);

var leftChannelDelayNode = context.createDelay();
leftChannelDelayNode.delayTime.value = 0.10;
channelSplitterNode.connect(leftChannelDelayNode, 0);

// Node to control the track's overall volume
var volumeGainNode = context.createGain();

// I think this might be where I mess up
sourceNode.connect(leftChannelGainNode);
sourceNode.connect(leftChannelDelayNode);
sourceNode.connect(volumeGainNode);
volumeGainNode.connect(context.destination);

// Change gain at any time like so 
// volumeGainNode.gain.value = 1.50;
// leftChannelDelayNode.delayTime.value = 1.50;
// leftChannelGainNode.gain.value = 2.00;
```

How should the connections be made to accomplish my goals?

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvvozsot/183/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to connect the nodes as a chain; think of it as a concept of patch cables.

You will also need a [merger node](https://devdocs.io/dom/channelmergernode) to combine the split channels (see [this example](https://devdocs.io/dom/channelsplitternode) for its usage).

So, the connection list would be:

- source → splitter node
- left channel → gain node
- gain node → delay node
- delay node + right channel → merger node
- merger node → output

In graphic form:

[image: flow diagram]

**Update** Adding technical details (updated from Dan P.'s fiddle):

The chain using code would then be:

```
// nodes
sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(audioPlayer);
splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2);
gainL = context.createGain();
delayL = context.createDelay();
merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);
gainGeneral = context.createGain();        

// source to splitter
sourceNode.connect(splitter);

// left channel to gain
splitter.connect(gainL, 0);

// gain to delay
gainL.connect(delayL);

// delay to merger
delayL.connect(merger, 0, 0);

// remeber right channel to merger here:
splitter.connect(merger, 1, 1);

// merged signal to common gain node
merger.connect(gainGeneral);

// gain to output
gainGeneral.connect(context.destination);
```

### Demo:

```js
var gainL, delayL, gainGeneral, merger, splitter, context, sourceNode, audioPlayer;
audioPlayer = $('#audioPlayer')[0];
$('#play').on('click', function(){audioPlayer.play();});

context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// nodes
sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(audioPlayer);
splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2);
gainL = context.createGain();
delayL = context.createDelay();
merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);
gainGeneral = context.createGain();        

// source to splitter
sourceNode.connect(splitter);

// left channel to gain
splitter.connect(gainL, 0);

// gain to delay
gainL.connect(delayL);

// delay to merger
delayL.connect(merger, 0, 0);

// remeber right channel to merger here:
splitter.connect(merger, 1, 1);

// merged signal to common gain node
merger.connect(gainGeneral);

// gain to output
gainGeneral.connect(context.destination);

$('.adjust-stereo-btn').on('click', function () {
 var action = $(this).data('action');

  switch (action) {
    case 'normal':
      gainL.gain.value = 1.00;
      delayL.delayTime.value = 0.00;
      break;
    case 'wide':
      // I recommend values <10ms as above our brain is able to separate the signal.
      // Delays may cause phase issues too (if using loudspeakers)
      gainL.gain.value = 1.0;  // set to 1 for this demo
      delayL.delayTime.value = 5/1000;
      break;
    case 'wider':
      gainL.gain.value = 1.0;
      delayL.delayTime.value = 10/1000;
      break;
  }
});

$('.adjust-volume-btn').on('click', function () {
 var action = $(this).data('action');
  switch (action) {
    case 'normal':
      gainGeneral.gain.value = 1.00;
      break;
    case 'loud':
      gainGeneral.gain.value = 2.00;
      break;
    case 'louder':
      gainGeneral.gain.value = 3.00;
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;">Play Track</button>

<div>
  <h1>Adjust Stereo Width</h1>
  <button class="adjust-stereo-btn" data-action="normal">Normal</button>
  <button class="adjust-stereo-btn" data-action="wide">Wide</button>
  <button class="adjust-stereo-btn" data-action="wider">Wider</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Adjust Volume</h1>
  <button class="adjust-volume-btn" data-action="normal">Normal</button>
  <button class="adjust-volume-btn" data-action="loud">Loud</button>
  <button class="adjust-volume-btn" data-action="louder">Louder</button>
</div>

<audio crossorigin="anonymous" id="audioPlayer" src="https://www.faceflow.com/beam_me_up_mast.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helps understanding. I'm still not getting the results I want however (i.e. the playback starts with the right channel being louder without clicking any of the adjustment button), and I think one reason might be because of the merging. I made a live demo to make this easier to work with: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvvozsot/183

Comment: @DanP. the only thing that seem to be missing in the fiddle is that the right channel from the splitter has not been connected back into the merger; splitter.connect(merger, 1, 1); https://jsfiddle.net/Lvvozsot/189/

Comment: Thanks, working out! One thing I noticed is a clicking sound when changing the delay. Using `setValueAtTime` fixed it, e.g. `delayL.delayTime.setValueAtTime(0.005, audioContext.currentTime);`. Thank you!